"Brownian" motion on pseudo-Riemannian manifolds
On a Riemannian manifold $(M,g)$ one can write down the Laplace-Beltrami operator in local coordinates as
$$\Delta_M = \frac{1}{\sqrt{\det g}} \partial_i\left(\sqrt{\det g} g^{ij} \partial_j \right)$$
where we are using the Einstein summation convention. A probabilist will then say that Brownian motion is the stochastic process $X=(X_t)$ whose infinitesimal generator is $\mathscr{G}=\frac12 \Delta_M$. Thus, the transition density of $X_t$, conditional on $X_0=x_0$ $p(t,x)$ solves the Fokker-Planck equation $p_t = \frac12 \Delta_m p$ with IC $p(0, x)=\delta_{x_0}(x)$. This gives the density with respect to the volume measure $\nu(dx) = \sqrt{\det g(x)}dx$ on $M$. Once you have the generator, it is easy to write down the SDE for $X$, valid until the first exit time of a given chart, as
$$ dX_t = \frac12 \nabla_g \cdot g^{-1}(X_t) dt + g^{-1/2} (X_t)dB_t,$$
where $B_t$ is a Euclidean BM in $\mathbb{R}^d$, if $M$ has intrinsic dimension $d$.
More generally, given a paraboloic or elliptic operator $\mathscr{G}$, there is a whole nice Markov semigroup theory about $P_t = e^{\mathscr{G} t}$.
Question:
How does this generalize to pseudo-Riemannian manifolds?

We can still write down the Laplace-Beltrami operator, but now we replace $\sqrt{\det g}$ with $\sqrt{ |\det g|}$ since the metric tensor is no longer PD everywhere.
If $M=\mathbb{R}^{1,n}$, Minkowki space, with $g=\operatorname{diag}(-c^2, 1, 1,\dotsc, 1)$, then it is easy to see that
$$\Delta_M = -\frac{1}{c^2}\frac{\partial^2}{\partial t^2} +\Delta_x =: \square,$$
where $\Delta_x$ is the Euclidean Laplacian on $x=(x^1, \dotsc, x^n)$ and $\square$ is the d'Alembert operator.

If one were to think about the analog of the Fokker-Planck equation, then you could either think about solutions $p(t,x)$ to
$$\frac{\partial p}{\partial t} = \frac12 \square p$$
or perhaps solutions $p(s, t, x)$
$$\frac{\partial p}{\partial s} = -\frac{1}{2c^2} \frac{\partial^2 p}{\partial t^2} +\frac12 \Delta_x p.$$
What is the difference between these two choices? Advantages of one over the other? Has this been done already? Is there a standard literature reference? These motions are going to be different than what we normally think of as Brownian motion which diffuses at infinite propagation speeds. I realize it's somewhat of a broad question but can anyone point me to work already done on this subject, especially from the probabilist's perspective? I have found a paper by O'Hara that derives the second Fokker-Planck analog as a discrete time approximation with a "universal" time parameter.

For simplicity, let's stay in $\mathbb R^2,.$ It sounds like you want an SDE for a process whose generator is $\partial_x^2-\partial_y^2,.$ This can be written as
$$
(\partial_x,\partial_y)\pmatrix{1&0\0&-1}\pmatrix{\partial_x\\partial_y},.
$$
That matrix is not PSD so there is no matrix $\boldsymbol{\sigma}$ s.t. $\boldsymbol{\sigma\sigma}^\top$ gives us that matrix in the generator. But to formulate the SDE we need
$$
d\boldsymbol{x}_t=\boldsymbol{\sigma}\cdot d\boldsymbol{w}_t,.
$$

Cont.. I have no idea what O'Hara has done. There seem however efforts to do something in these directions. arxiv.org/abs/1306.0857. Looks complicated.

@KurtG. Interesting thanks for the paper. I should clarify that I do not expect to find diffusion SDEs, for the reason you demonstrated. In the Minkowski space $\mathbb{R}^{1,1}$ you can show the first "Fokker-Planck" candidate I wrote, $p_t=\frac12 \square p$, IIRC, governs the telegraph process $X_t=X_0+c\int_0^t (-1)^{N_s} ds$ where $N$ is Poisson process with appropriate rate, and this can be described by $dX_t = V_t dt$ and $dV_t=-2V_{t^-} dN_t$ where $V_t=(-1)^{N_t}$. Note $(X,V)$ is Markov but $X$ is not and $X_t$ satisfies $|X_t-x_0|\leq ct$ a.s (stays within the light cone at $x_0$)

After searching more I finally found some literature that satisfies my curiosities. I will briefly review some of it here, with links to some of the papers.
As noted in the comments, if you want to solve for $p(t,x)$ in
$$p_t = \frac12 \square p,$$
with initial position $x_0$, i.e. $p(0, x)=\delta(x-x_0)$ and zero initial velocity
then this density governs a non-Markovian process $(X_t)_{t\geq 0}$ that travels at the constant velocity $c$, switching directions randomly. If you want a process that travels at a constant speed, is Lorentz invariant, and is also Markov, then you are left with constant trivial processes. See Dudley (1966).
For processes that travel at speeds less than $c$, we can say a bit more. I will outline the construction for $\mathbb{R}^{1,2}$. Let $\mathcal{U}_+=\{(t,x,y): x^2+y^2-t^2=-1, t>0\}$. Let
$$\phi(t,x,y) = \frac{1}{1+t}(x,y).$$
It is easy to show that $\phi(\mathcal{U}_+)\subset \mathbb{D}$ where $\mathbb{D}:=\{(u,v): u^2+v^2<1\}$ and that in fact $\phi:\mathcal{U}_+\to \mathbb{D}$ is a bijection. In fact, if $g=\operatorname{diag}(-1, 1,1)$ is the metric tensor for $\mathbb{R}^{1,2}$, and $\psi:=\phi^{-1}$ then the metric tensor in the new coordinates is
$$\tilde{g} = D\psi^T g D\psi=\frac{4}{(1-u^2-v^2)^2}I_{2\times 2}$$
Hence $g$ restricted to $\mathcal{U}_+$ is isometric with the Poincare disk model for hyperbolic space. Great, but so what?
Well, any timelike path $\vec{\gamma}(s)$ in $\mathbb{R}^{1,2}$ can be reparameterized to $\vec{\beta}(s)=\vec{\gamma}\circ h(s)$ so that $\vec{\beta}'(s) \in \mathcal{U}_+$. This is not difficult to see: just apply chain rule and solve for $h$ such that $g(\beta', \beta')=-1$.
Thus, we can get random timelike paths $\vec{X}_t$ as follows. We let $(X, X')$ be the position and velocity process in phase-space, WLOG taking $X_s'\in \mathcal{U}_+$ for all $s\geq 0$. Thus, by the FTC
$$\vec{X}_s = \vec{x}_0+ \int_0^s \vec{X}_w'dw.$$
Since $\mathcal{U}_+$ has a Riemannin manifold structure, we can take $\vec{X}_s'$ to be a Brownian motion relative to the proper metric tensor. In other words, let $(U_s, V_s)$ denote a hyperbolic Brownian motion in $(\mathbb{D}, \tilde{g}).$ Then define $\vec{X}_s' = \phi^{-1}(U_s, V_s)$
which is explicitly given by
$$\phi^{-1}(u,v ) = \left(\frac{1+r^2}{1-r^2}, \frac{2u}{1-r^2}, \frac{2v}{1-r^2}\right),$$
where $r^2=u^2+v^2$. Then, of course, we just integrate. Below is a simulation of a realization of a single sample path.
Below are two citations, one generalizing this to Schwarzchild spacetime, and general Lorentzian manifolds, as well as Dudley's paper that, essentially started this whole topic.
Dudley, R. M., Lorentz-invariant Markov processes in relativistic phase space, Ark. Mat. 6, 241-268 (1966). ZBL0171.39105.
Franchi, Jacques; Le Jan, Yves, Relativistic diffusions and Schwarzschild geometry, Commun. Pure Appl. Math. 60, No. 2, 187-251 (2007). ZBL1130.83006.
